# Запуск exe файла много раз параллельно

Tags: python, многопоточность, subprocess

Всем привет, есть файл .exe который выполняется +- 10 секунд, запускать этот файл обычным циклом очень долго, так как запустить его нужно много раз.
Я решил использовать потоки для этого:

```
import subprocess
import threading

mutex = threading.Lock()

i = 0

def worker():
    global i
    
    while True:
        mutex.acquire()
        i += 1
        mutex.release() 

        cmd = f"C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\main.exe"
        
        
        returned_output = str(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
        print(returned_output)
                


def run_workers(count):
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker) for i in range(0, count)]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()  # каждый поток должен быть запущен

    for thread in threads:
        print("Поток завершился")
        thread.join()  # дожидаемся исполнения всех потоков


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_workers(50)
```

main.exe не сильно нагружает компьютер, по этому 50 потоков нагрузит на 20% компьютер.
Проблема в том что, когда запускаешь, он все равно медленно работает, а в диспетчере задач показано что запущено 3-4 main.exe.
В чем проблема? почему вместо 50 запускается 3-4 main.exe, и к тому же через время и они останавливаются.

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш main.exe в принципе позволяет запускать себя несколько раз?

Comment: main.exe это моя программа на go lagn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через `asyncio` вместо `threading`:

```
import asyncio

i = 0


async def worker():
    global i
    
    while True:
        i += 1

        cmd = "C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\main.exe"
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
            cmd,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
        )

        stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()

        print(f'[{cmd!r} exited with {proc.returncode}]')
        if stdout:
            print(f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode()}')
        if stderr:
            print(f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode()}')


async def run_workers(count):
    workers = [worker() for i in range(0, count)]
    await asyncio.gather(*workers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_workers(50))
```

На основе документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html

---

Вариант реализации в одном потоке и без асинхронности, просто в бесконечном цикле проверяем состояние процессов через [`Popen.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll), поддерживаем количество живых процессов равным `count`:

```
import subprocess
import time

cmd = "C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\main.exe"


def run_workers(count):
    processes = []
    
    while True:
        alive_processes = []
        
        # Вывод результата завершенных процессов, оставляем в списке только живые процессы
        for proc in processes:
            if proc.poll() is None:
                alive_processes.append(proc)
            else:
                stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
                
                print(f'[{cmd!r} exited with {proc.returncode}]')
                
                if stdout:
                    print(f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode()}')
                if stderr:
                    print(f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode()}')
        
        processes = alive_processes
        
        # Если живых процессов меньше count, запускаем дополнительные
        for _ in range(len(alive_processes), count):
            processes.append(subprocess.Popen([cmd]))
        
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_workers(50)
```

Comment: Все как бы хорошо, но очень нагружать стало + мне нужно к sqlite3 подключатся. Я еще не особо знаю асинхронное программирование.
Может кто-то все же знает причину такого поведения потоков?

Comment: @Eveee без понятия, что там с потоками. Могу предположить, что какое-то системное ограничение количества потоков. Если с асинхронностью сильно нагружает - уменьшите количество воркеров, все равно не будет быстрее работать, если количество процессов больше чем количество ядер процессора, оставьте одно ядро свободным.

Comment: @Eveee добавил вариант однопоточной реализации (для запуска новых процессов не нужна многопоточность).